# Converting from MFC dialog units to pixels

Tags: c#, c++, mfc, resources

Using C#, how would I convert from dialog units (used in resource files to specify height/width) to pixels?

Answer (score 4):

There's a WinAPI function to map dialog units to pixels:

[MapDialogRect function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645502.aspx)

Comment: Actually, there's also MFC wrapper:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hb7x4ze.aspx